# Can't authenticate against a 389DS server. I suspect it's a SSSD issue on client side

Tags: ldap, pam, sssd, nss, 389-ds

I'm running a 389DS LDAPS server (with self-signed certificates) on a Fedora 30 remote machine called "miservidor.midominio.local". There I have a typical directory containing user and group entries.

I can retrieve directory data from another Fedora 30 machine (the client's one) wihout any problem. For instance, executing this command ("usu1ldap" is the name of an user located inside a "usuarios" organizationalunit)...:

*LDAPTLS_REQCERT=never ldapsearch -H ldaps://miservidor.midominio.local -b "dc=midominio,dc=local" uid=usu1ldap*

...I get:

[image]

But I want to login in client machine with "usu1ldap". So I've configured /etc/sssd/sssd.conf file in client machine like this...:

[image]

...I've executed *sudo authselect select sssd* to "automagically" configure NSS/PAM frameworks and finally I've restarted sssd service.

However, something doesn't work: *getent passwd* doesn't show "usu1ldap" user and, obviously, *id usu1ldap* retrieves "unknown user" too

What am I doing wrong? I've tried to grasp sssd's log files but without any clue. I'm a bit desperated...

Thanks a lot for your patience.

NOTE: Notice that in sssd.conf file I've had to assign the name and password of directory's manager to "ldap_default_bind_dn" and "ldap_default_authtok" lines respectively because my 389DS server by default doesn't allow anonymous queries and I don't know how to change this (yet).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I’ve solved the issue: I forgot adding the services=nss,pam line in “/etc/sssd/sssd.conf” file (below [sssd] section. That was all. Oh my… I thought systemd could care of this (see https://docs.pagure.org/SSSD.sssd/design_pages/systemd_activatable_responders.html) but it seems it doesn’t.

For knowing all the full story until arriving to this (happy) end, you can read this full post: https://ask.fedoraproject.org/t/cant-authenticate-against-a-389ds-server-i-suspect-its-a-sssd-problem-on-the-client-side/3347

Thanks anyway